# java.lang.NullPointerException: Error while using RecyclerView.Widget

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, nullpointerexception

I am trying to add a list of audio files to my fragment. I have also set the layout manager to recycler view. I have also added dependencies to gradle build

Here is the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.musicplayer.AllSongs.onCreateView(AllSongs.java:35)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2698)
```

I am trying to get all songs in my all songs fragment.
Here is my code which shows error:

```
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        recyclerView = recyclerView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        if (!(musicFiles.size() < 1))
        {
            musicAdapter = new MusicAdapter(getContext(),musicFiles);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(musicAdapter);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        }
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_songs_tab, container, false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error is fixed here is the solution

**What I have done:**

earlier I was returning `onCreateView` function but after returning inflater in `View` my code was fixed and list of audio files was shown

```
 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_songs_tab, container, false);

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

            musicAdapter = new MusicAdapter(getContext(), musicFiles);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(musicAdapter);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false));
        musicAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            return view;
```

Comment: Providing blob of code without explanation is quite counter educational. Please provide more info what was the problem

Comment: I don't have much knowledge of explaining, but ill try my best to explain what I have done to fix my code

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_songs_tab, container, false);

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        musicFiles = new ArrayList();
        if (!(musicFiles.size() < 1))
        {
            musicAdapter = new MusicAdapter(getContext(),musicFiles);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(musicAdapter);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        }

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: i have tried it but    " java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference "  this error pops

Comment: @Mad_Flasher_oo7 `musicFiles=new ArrayList()`;

Comment: @Mad_Flasher_oo7 You can

Comment: thank you so much it worked but its empty logcat shows No adapter attached 
can you help me with it?

Comment: @Mad_Flasher_oo7 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141729/recyclerview-no-adapter-attached-skipping-layout

Answer (score 2):

Your app is crash at below line

```
 recyclerView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
```

**Do as per below**

```
 onCreateView(.....){
 View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_songs_tab, container, false);
 recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
 ....
 ....
 return v ;
 }
```